# Same Data returned from different Div with same ID in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following snippet of code where I have dynamically generated the divs and the ID of the divs are based on the event date such as "Tue26Nov". If there is only one event for the day, that means there will be only one div with this ID, but if I have 2 or more events on the same date, I will have 2 or more divs with same ID, and in that case, the JQuery returns the data from the First div itself, but I want it to return the data from the three divs seperately. Code Below:

```
<div id="WedNov27">Event 1</div>
<div id="WedNov27">Event 2</div>
<div id="WedNov27">Event 3</div>
```

What I am doing is that on the click, I am printing the data from these divs to another div, but it is printing following

Event 1
Event 1
Event 1

rather than

Event 1
Event 2
Event 3

You can check my fiddle here at http://jsfiddle.net/AFHfn/118/

Answer (score 2):

The anwer is in the question ;)

An ID should be unique, you can you classes if you want multiple elements with the same 'name'

```
<div class="WedNov27">Event n</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have duplicate `id` attributes, which is invalid. Use a `class` instead to group them.

The reason you are seeing the same value on each iteration is because jQuery only returns the value from the first element found when selecting by an `id`.

Comment: I made a slight change to my fiddle, instead of ID, i made the class dynamic, it does work but prints the date more than once. http://jsfiddle.net/AFHfn/119/

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, I recommend avoiding IDs — the unexpected behaviour is a result of using them in a way they shouldn't be expected to work. Unlike the other answers, I suggest avoiding classes and using a data attribute more specific to your code:  `data-date="WedNov27"` perhaps? The syntax for retrieving would be slightly more verbose: `$( '[data-date=WedNov27]' )`, but the significance is much clearer.

Comment: @Chunkz hey, sorry it took me so long to get around to this. [Fixed your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zbFLn/). I changed some of the variable names too: throughout your code there's the implication that any given date is an 'id', when it isn't (an id is a unique identifier, and obviously what you're referring to is not a unique identifier since there can be several element on the same date).